# what's wrong with this statement 'the about page' w'ont be rendered i am using django 1.11.9

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

Hello everyone i wanted to know if i am making any mistake in this view :

***** This is he main project urls module*****

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from users import views as user_views
from blog import views as blog_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^about/', include('blog.urls'))
    url(r'^register/', user_views.register, name='register'),
   
    
]
```

***** This is the blog urls module*****

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.home, name ='blog-home'),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name ='blog-about') 
]
```

*****this is the views module*****

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts' : Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context, { 'title':'Home' })

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', { 'title':'About' })
```

*****this is the html page to be rendered*****

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        {% if title %}
            <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
        {% else %}
            <title>Django-blog</title>
        {% endif %}
        <h1 class="heading">About Us Page Content</h1>
    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Please edit the question and include *what* is not working. What tex expected output is, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You pass only one context, so you should add extra data to the dictionary:

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'posts' : Post.objects.all(),
        'title': 'Home'  # ← second element
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```